# python2.7 module dir not recognizing submodules

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-packaging

I have a python module dir set up like so:

```
versions/__init__.py
versions/v1_0.py
versions/v2_0.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty but each  `v*.py` file has some functions defined. I then try importing all the submodules with `from versions import *` but when I use `dir()` to print out all my loaded modules they are not listed and I am unable to use any of the submodule functions such as `v1_0.update()`

am I setting up my `versions` module incorrectly?

here is a minimum reproducible example:

below are the results of a `find` and `more` command that show the file structure as well as the file contents of each python file.

```
$ find .
.
./versions
./versions/__init__.py
./versions/__init__.pyc
./versions/v1_0.pyc
./versions/v1_0.py
```

```
$ more versions/*.py
::::::::::::::
versions/__init__.py
::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::
versions/v1_0.py
::::::::::::::
def update():
  pass
```

with this setup and with my pwd at `.` I did the following:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from versions import *
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> versions.v1_0.update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'versions' is not defined
>>> from versions.v1_0 import update
>>> update
<function update at 0x10428c0>
```

Comment: have you tried import module by module like: from versions.v1_0.py import method_one

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] of your code, just to be sure nothing important is being left out?

Comment: @ShadowRanger see my update post.

Comment: does your `__init__.py` define an `__all__`?

Comment: no, my `__init__.py` is completely empty

Comment: using `from versions import v1_0` does seem to work with this setup. very strange...

Comment: If `__init__.py` is empty, then `from versions import *` will not have anything

Comment: In general, though, you *shouldn't use `from module import *`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) I found that if `__all__` is not defined then `from module import *` will only initialize `module` and then import any names explicitly defined in `module`. so in my case since `versions/__init__.py` does not explicitly define `v1_0` it is not imported.